# How to put shebang in PHP 5.4 CLI and not trigger Deprecated?

Tags: php, shell

[PHP manual says](http://php.net/manual/pl/features.commandline.usage.php):

> On Unix systems, the special #! (or "shebang") first line should be added to PHP scripts so that the system can automatically tell which program should run the script.

But when I do it on machine with PHP 5.4.36 installed, I get:

> PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0

I do not want to allow hash comments globally. They are deprecated and warning is just. But on the other hand, I do want to have shebang available, and not triggering warnings. After all, manual says I *should* use them. How can I get it to work?

My script at the moment looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
```

I also tried, with exactly the same effect:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

Comment: The error doesn't look to be on your script, but in the ming.ini file.  You only need a shebang line on the script you are executing in linux, not any included files.

Comment: You should ensure that the very first line of your file has "#! /path/to/php" and nothing else. Also, are you sure that you need it for your use? That is for when you intend to run php scripts from linux, and is not needed if it is to be served to a web browser

Comment: @Devon I added code to my question.

Comment: Type:
$ which php
and you will get something like -
/usr/bin/php
there should be no spaces

Comment: As @Devon has already said, the warning you are reporting is from a **different** file, which is loaded as part of your startup process.

Comment: @Ajaypayne yes, I am using CLI, I know what it is and I recognized I'm in shell and not in web browser... I even tagged my question as [tag:shell].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't caused by your script, it is caused by the ming.ini file. You only need a shebang line on the script you are executing in linux, not any included files.

Remove the `#` comments in ming.ini (ini files should use `;`).

Comment: Oh. I trusted distro-provided files a bit to much. But fun fact - this error was not shown when I ran my file using `php file.php`. Strange. Well, glad it worked.

Comment: That is strange, error_reporting or the include files must be getting set differently somewhere.

Comment: Don't know, and really - don't care. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes :) File is fixed, and in my php code I'll set error reporting levels as needed.